# re-install an npm module of a file path doesn't work in react

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-pack

Hi I'm facing some problem when re-installing my own created npm package.
this is the script that I use:

```
cd ../../my-npm-package
npm install
npm run build-package ("build-package": "rm -rf lib && tsc --outDir ./lib --declaration --noEmit false && npm pack")
cd ../../my-current-project
npm uninstall my-npm-package
npm install ../../my-npm-package.tgz
npm install
```

interestingly this works at the first time but when I execute it again with changes in my-npm-package it doesn't reflect the changes of the package. Which is more rare is that in the npm modules the package is updated, but checking in react files in the browser the package is not updated.

the only workaround that works is deleting the all node_modules of my-current-project and execute the script. however this last to much.

Is something that I'm doing wrong to only install my created package and when doing: npm i my-npm-package it is update.

thanks so much for your help.